# encoding jsonl file as utf-8 failing in Python 2.7

Tags: json, encoding, python-2.x

I am currently working with Python 2.7.7 and I am trying to read in a jsonl file from standard input via the console:

```
python my_single_jsonl.jsonl | my_python_code.py
```

This is the code I am using to read std_in:

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os
import json
import sys

def extract_jsonl_data():

    json_as_list= []

    for line in sys.stdin:
        json_as_list.append(json.loads(line))


    return json_as_list
```

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file single_jsonl.jsonl on
> line 2, but no encoding declared; see
> http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

The error appears to be caused by a non-ASCII '-' character in the source jsonl file.  I have looked at similar stories around Python 2.x encoding and they suggest the following:

1. Add magic comment to head of the .py file similar to:

   `# coding=utf-8`
2. Import unicode handling from Py3:

   `from __future__ import unicode_literals`
3. converting the imported jsonl string on the fly:

   `myjson_str.encoding('utf-8')`

I've tried all three approaches and nothing seems to change this error.  Are there any other approaches.  Editing the source file isn't possible in this case.

I'm working on a macbook, using Atom as my source code editor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate your [mcve]. At least, how do you read `single_jsonl.jsonl` file ?

Comment: JosefZ  Have added simplified function for reading in jsonl and parsing it.  Let me know if any further info would be useful.